# Question about method put "java" in android

Tags: java, android

What mean `Non-static method 'put(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' cannot be referenced from a static context` in android studio?

[image]

Comment: Next time you have that type of question, also remember to add the relevant code in the body of the question itself, rather than just a print screen. So other can copy/paste your code in their own Visual Studio and help you even more efficiently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
contentValues.put("name",name);
```

instead of

```
ContentValues.put("name",name);
```

Comment: Hi @mhmd if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: okay done! @Gabriele Mariotti

Comment: @mhmd what the message means, now is that you used the method on the class itself (starting with a capital) and not on the variable called `contentValues` (staring with a lower-cased letter) that you instantiated on the line above.

Answer (score 0):

It means exactly that, you are calling put as a static method and it is not static.
Yo are doing:

```
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
```

but in the next line you are calling:

```
ContentValues.put("name", name)
```

You see... 
If not... what you have to do is:

```
contentValues.put("name", name)
```

and that solves the problem

Comment: thanks u @charli3B !